# Does Marlowe Run have the capability to mint NFTs?

Tags: nft, marlowe

I know the easiest way is to mint via https://www.nft-maker.io/ or https://cardano-native-token.com/ but if I want to mint it on my own, is minting in the Terminal the only option?
https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/native-tokens/getting-started-with-native-tokens.html

I was wondering if Marlowe Run has the feature to mint NFTs in addition to creating smart contracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not planned for Marlowe to have a feature to mint NFTs or native tokens.

However, it will use tokens internally to represent the ownership of a role in contact.

Answer (score -1):

> ...is minting in the Terminal the only option?

Yes, right now the terminal is the only first party option.

As Marek pointed out, the community may have other ways. https://satran004.medium.com/cardano-client-lib-minting-a-new-native-token-in-java-part-iii-1a94a21cfeeb looks like a good tutorial if you're in the Java programming ecosystem.

If you are not a programmer or terminal guru, I'm pretty sure a web version and/or Daedalus version is mostly likely in the works. The Daedalus version will supposedly allow you to do some ongoing "management" tasks of your minted tokens.

I'm pretty sure they demoed a web page for minting Native Tokens on one of the monthly updates. Charles in one of his AMA also said he wanted to bring that management to both the web, then eventually Daedalus.

> I was wondering if Marlowe Run has the feature to mint NFTs...

No, no minting functionality. That tool is specifically for creating smart contracts.

Comment: I think this question is specific to Marlowe.

Comment: Also, it is not true right now the terminal is the only option to mint NFT. There is tons of libraries already that support this. https://satran004.medium.com/cardano-client-lib-minting-a-new-native-token-in-java-part-iii-1a94a21cfeeb

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, considering the question was about a web tool that targets "little to no programming", I was reluctant to provide answers that didn't meet the same standard.