# NFT Support For Marlowe

Tags: marlowe-pioneer-program

[A Marlowe contract for a bank loan is linked here](https://gist.github.com/johnshearing/79e4e10cf7ad5860a89c932780e65191):
This was homework for Marlowe Pioneers - Lesson 4.
If you run the contract in the Marlowe Playground you will see that if the borrower makes all the payments on time then the bank returns all the ADA to the borrower and the contract ends. Returning the money to the borrower seems to simulate the bank is giving the borrower a title to a property. I am wondering if giving an NFT to represent the property deed is already possible using Marlowe. If not, then I am wondering when NFT support is going to be added to Marlowe.
I think that it may be possible to do this now or in the future because of [the stackexchange post linked here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/799/does-marlowe-run-have-the-capability-to-mint-nfts). Is this something that should be [added to the ACTUS](http://demo.actusfrf.org/) demos?

Is it possible to expand the Marlow contract linked above to deliver an NFT representing a property deed if the borrower makes all the payments on time? If so, will we be taught this skill?

Much thanks

Comment: Thanks to Hernan Rajchert, the contract linked above now uses a native token as seen in his solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marlowe already has the notion of MultiValue asset, which is what you need to trade custom tokens. Instead of using the ADA token, use one that represent your deed.

The minting of that NFT is done outside of Marlowe, but after you have it, you can put it into a Marlowe contract with a Deposit.

[image: Blockly Deposit custom NFT]

Useful link: https://docs.cardano.org/native-tokens/learn